# Finding local minima/maxima without calculus: name of technique?

Tags: algorithm

If `f` is a continuous function on `[a,b]` and has one local minimum in 
`[a,b]` and no local maxima in `[a,b]`, you can find that minimum to 
arbitrary precision by repeatedly cutting the interval into thirds, 
observing the values of `f` on the endpoints of those thirds, and 
repeating.

What is the name of this technique? Google is unhelpful, and keeps 
leading me to calculus-based techniques.

For reference, I've implemented this technique in Perl here:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bclib.pl#L1715

Comment: When dealing with unwieldy, iteractive design equation in engineering school (meatspace, not software), we cut into half-intervals and evaluated the midpoints. Called it bisection or interval-halving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you aren't cutting the interval in half (but instead in thirds) the term *[Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)* doesn't quite apply.  Instead the term *[Golden Section Search](http://books.google.com/books?id=AtiDhx2bsiMC&pg=PA67&dq=golden+section+search&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VGmGUuH3IOegiQKcyIHIBQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=golden%20section%20search&f=false)* is more applicable.  It efficiently organizes function evaluations and has proven optimality properties.  The shrink ratio is [φ-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), or about 0.618.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I also learned my technique of using equal-sized intervals is inefficient. It turns out what I was doing is the weaker ternary search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search)